# Running Python2.7 script in C++ using #include "Python.h"

Tags: python, c++, debugging, visual-studio-2015, include

I would like to run a Python script that uses a library that only works with Python2.7 in a c++ Program.

I run this in Release mode because i don't have python27_d.lib under VS 2015.

```
PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFunc, *pValue;
Py_Initialize();
std::string name = "C:/pathToProgamm/pythonHTTPS.py"
pName = PyString_fromString(name.c_strg());
pModule = Pyimport_Import(pName);
pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);
```

Here I get the error python27.pdb not loaded

I tried to solve it by changing to "Only specified modules" (from "All modules, unless excluded") under Debugging->Symbols in VS 2015 but then I get
Symbol loading for python27.dll was skipped because it is not specified in the included modules list. I also tried to download the pdb file and point to it but this also doesn't work.

What I want to do is that:

```
if (pName = PyString_FromString(name_i.c_str()))
    {
        if (pModule = PyImport_Import(pName))
        {
            if (pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule))
            {
                if (pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, NULL))
                {
                    std::cout << "success" << std::endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << "failed pFunc" << std::endl;
                    return;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "failed pDict" << std::endl;
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "failed pModule" << std::endl;
            return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "failed pName" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
```

but the result of this is --> failed pModule

so the error is in pModule=Pyimport_import(pName);

could anybody tell me why this fails and how to get the debugging running for my python version (2.7.14)

Comment: Just build your project, does it build successfully? If you use the VS2015, I think you would add the symbol manually like this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/debugging-symbols-for-mixed-mode, and it has 32/64 bit version. In release mode, please make sure that your code was not optimized. Set Disabled/Od for Optimization in your project property page. This video also shared how to config the debug mode for Python  here even if it was in VS2010:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y_eh00oE5rI, maybe it could provide you a way to use the debug mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define _DEBUG_WAS_DEFINED 1
#undef _DEBUG
#endif

#include <Python.h>

#ifdef _DEBUG_WAS_DEFINED 1
#define _DEBUG 1
#endif
```

That solved the Debugging errors for me (I still can't debug in the python script but I don't need to).

It is important to give the name of the python module without .py.

Comment: Since you have resolved this issue. If possible, you could mark your solution as the answer. Have a nice day:)